# Changing server in SIPDROID

Tags: android

I got the source code of sipdroid following the link 
http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/checkout
using the command :: svn checkout http://sipdroid.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ sipdroid-read-only

Sipdroid uses pbxes.org to tunnel voip calls. But I want to configure this and use different sipserver to make voip calls.

As a new comer in this field I need help and suggestion about how to change this server.

Answer (score 1):

In `org.sipdroid.sipua.ui.Settings.java`, you can find this:

```
public static final String  DEFAULT_SERVER = "pbxes.org";
```

Replace it with your name.

Answer (score 0):

There is a search box on the page you linked to (search trunk).

http://www.google.com/codesearch#search&q=pbxes.org+package:http://sipdroid%5C.googlecode%5C.com

It seems that the server setting is in `Settings.java`.